# lack of geometry on the render, but not in the viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I've got a scene with paper sheets moving along paths (with a modifier).
But there is something weird : while everything looks fine on the viewport, it seems that there is a lack of geometry when rendering (we can see kind of horizontal lines on the paper).

[image]

I checked : I have soft shading enabled on the meshes, I have a subdivision modifier enabled (on render too), and I also checked the resolution of the curves (12 on preview, 0 on render)

So why this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Check that the number of subdivisions is equal or higher than the ones for the viewport.

Comment: already checked, it's not that...

Comment: Have you not answered your own question? if you have geometry with curves and you have the render view to 0? it wont be shown, but 12 in the viewport - try making both 12 and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @Facity : 0 = use of previous resolution (12 in this case)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your modifier settings?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is happening because I use 'Simple' subsurf, not 'Catmull-Clark' !

Anyway, seems there is a bug since it doesn't look the same in the viewport... ?